# Gulp 4 tasks do not run in parallel

Tags: gulp

I have migrated from gulp 3 to 4. Everything was fine for a week, and then my build pipeline broke. I have a hugo website that should be rebuilt on `gulp build`.

The build task calls three other tasks in parallel: `gulp.parallel("css", "js", "hugo");`

When running `gulp build`, gulp claims it succeeded in 2.19 ms, which is too fast. These three task are supposed to output files to my dist folder, but it does not run my tasks at all.

Running the `css`, `js`, and `hugo` tasks manually in the terminal works as expected.

I am fairly new to gulp 4, so I suspect I am missing some detail. Here is my gulpfile:

```
import gulp from "gulp";
import cp from "child_process";
import gutil from "gulp-util";
import postcss from "gulp-postcss";
import cssImport from "postcss-import";
import cssnext from "postcss-cssnext";
import BrowserSync from "browser-sync";
import webpack from "webpack";
import webpackConfig from "./webpack.conf";
import cssnano from "cssnano";
import imagemin from "gulp-imagemin";
import imageminMozjpeg  from "imagemin-mozjpeg";
import webp from "imagemin-webp";
import gm from "gulp-gm";

const browserSync = BrowserSync.create();
const hugoBin = `./bin/hugo.${process.platform === "win32" ? "exe" : process.platform}`;
const defaultArgs = ["-d", "../dist", "-s", "site"];

if (process.env.DEBUG) {
  defaultArgs.unshift("--debug");
}

const hugo = (cb) => {
  buildSite(cb);
};
const hugoPreview = (cb) => {
  buildSite(cb, gulp.parallel("--buildDrafts", "--buildFuture"));
  cb();
};
const build  = (cb) => {
  gulp.parallel("css", "js", "hugo");
  cb();
};
const buildPreview = (cb) => {
  gulp.parallel("css", "js", "hugoPreview");
  cb();
};


const css = (cb) => {
  gulp.src("./src/css/*.css")
    .pipe(postcss([
      cssImport({
        from: "./src/css/main.css"
      }),
      cssnext(),
      cssnano(),
    ]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/css"))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
  cb();
};

const js = (cb) => {
  const myConfig = Object.assign({}, webpackConfig);

  webpack(myConfig, (err, stats) => {
    if (err) throw new gutil.PluginError("webpack", err);
    gutil.log("[webpack]", stats.toString({
      colors: true,
      progress: true
    }));
    browserSync.reload();
    cb();
  });
};

const webpConvert = (cb) => {
  gulp.src("./dist/img/**/*")
    .pipe(gm((gmfile) => {
      return gmfile.colorspace("rgb");
    }))
    .pipe(imagemin([
      webp({
        quality: 75
      })
    ]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/webp"));
  cb();
};

const imgSquash = (cb) => {
  return gulp.src("./site/static/img/**/*")
    .pipe(imagemin([
      imagemin.gifsicle({
        interlaced: true,
        optimizationLevel: 3
      }),
      imagemin.jpegtran({
        progressive: true
      }),
      imageminMozjpeg({
        quality: 80
      }),
      imagemin.optipng({
        optimizationLevel: 5
      }),
      imagemin.svgo({
        plugins: [{
          removeViewBox: true
        },
        {
          cleanupIDs: false
        }
        ]
      })
    ]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/img"));
};

const server = (cb) => {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "./dist"
    }
  });
  gulp.watch("./src/js/**/*.js", js);
  gulp.watch("./src/css/**/*.css", css);
  gulp.watch("./site/**/*", hugo);
  cb();
};

const buildSite = (cb, options) => {
  const args = options ? defaultArgs.concat(options) : defaultArgs;

  return cp.spawn(hugoBin, args, {
    stdio: "inherit"
  }).on("close", (code) => {
    if (code === 0) {
      browserSync.reload("notify:false");
      cb();
    } else {
      browserSync.notify("Hugo build failed :(");
      cb("Hugo build failed");
    }
  });
};

export {
  hugo,
  hugoPreview,
  build,
  buildPreview,
  css,
  js,
  webpConvert,
  imgSquash,
  server
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute callback in your tasks, gulp thinks that task is finished. Instead of calling callback you should return stream, so that gulp knows when task is finished.

You should change your tasks in something similar like this:

```
const css = (cb) => {
  return gulp.src("./src/css/*.css")
    .pipe(postcss([
      cssImport({
        from: "./src/css/main.css"
      }),
      cssnext(),
      cssnano(),
    ]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/css"))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
  // cb(); --comment this line
};
```

Add 'return' and comment line with cb();